# How can I get the new offset of a moved element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have an html table of data and each item in a row has a `list_position` field which can be changed and then all of the items will be reordered to match the  change on that item.

If I have a long list and I change an item from `list_position` value from 1 to 1000, I would like the browser to automatically scroll down to that item after the list is re-ordered.

Currently, with this code, I am scrolled to the item's *initial* position, not its current position.

```js
reorder: function (item, order, e) {

    // reorder stuff ...

    target = $(e.target).closest('tr');

    this.scrollTo(target);
},


scrollTo: function (target) {

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
    }, 1000);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just moved the element, its position likely hasn't yet been reflected in the DOM yet. One trick you can use is to wait until the browser's layout has been recalculated by using `setTimeout` with a timeout of `0`.

So instead of `this.scrollTo(target);`, try using:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.scrollTo(target);
}, 0);
```

For more information on why this works and when it's useful, please see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful).

---

EDIT: Thanks to Bill Criswell for pointing out the [`Vue.nextTick` function](http://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Understanding_Async_Updates), which is a more semantic way to wait for a DOM update (since you're already using the Vue.js library anyway). Using `Vue.nextTick`, your code would become the following:

```
Vue.nextTick(function() {
    this.scrollTo(target);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to bind this to the context `setTimeout(function() { this.scrollTo(target); }.bind(this), 0);` but now it works!

Comment: Vue has a `nextTick` function that's probably more reliable than this since it waits for Vue to say that all the DOM updates have bee completed (since it's async updated). You would use it like `this.$nextTick();` or `Vue.nextTick(..)` basically instead of the `setTimeout()`. http://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Understanding_Async_Updates